# Gunicorn does not serve updated Flask app (with Flask caching)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a very simple Flask app that caches a view function

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

@app.route("/")
@cache.cached(timeout=50)
def index():
    # code pulls data to put to index.html
    # ...

    return render_template('index.html')
```

I explicitly set a timeout of 50 seconds so that, I can retrieve new data and update `index.html`.

I'm serving my app through Gunicorn without any fancy parameters other than using an `eventlet` worker, but Gunicorn is not serving the updated `index.html`. I also have `nginx` in front of gunicorn, but I'm suspecting the issue is with Gunicorn...

Comment: What's the reason for updating `index.html` separately?  Can't you just compute the dynamic data in the view function, and pass to the template like `render_template('index.html', someVar = dynamic_info)`

Comment: How many gunicorn workers? Those cache timeouts apply per worker.

Comment: @v25, I'm updating `index.html` in python because I'm working with plotly dash which is a visualization library. I could pass the data to the template and use `d3.js` but would prefer not to if possible.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith, wow, I did not know that...I think 2 from using command `ps aux | grep myApp | grep -v grep | wc -l`. Since I have two workers, should I split my timeout in half to 25 sec per worker if I want a total of 50sec timeout?

Comment: Uncompiled Jinija2 templates are not supposed to be updated while the app is running. @pairwiseseq Have you had a look at: [https://dash.plot.ly/integrating-dash](https://dash.plot.ly/integrating-dash)?   This has a number of examples on how a dash app should be integrated with Flask.

Comment: @pairwiseseq It depends. @v25's comment is worth answering first. Are you changing the `index.html` template itself (which will run you afoul of a different caching mechanism), or values that feed in to the rendering of `index.html`? If the latter, you may need to revisit your caching and cache timeout assumptions.

Comment: @v25, thank you for pointing that out! Yes, I am actually integrating dash with Flask in that way. I just reduced the problem to Gunicorn and Flask as I felt that the issue was unrelated to dash. So indeed I am changing the Jinja template itself rather than updating it's running. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith, it is the former. I've tried using a `filesystem` cache but still no dice.

Comment: @pairwiseseq I'm confused what the question is, and why the need for caching?  `so that, I can retrieve new data and update index.html.` sounds like you were trying to buy a manual window to switch index.html with a version generated elsewhere. `but Gunicorn is not serving the updated index.html` I believe this is the desired behaviour of caching, unless the former is true and you were trying something else.  It may be worth posting a new clarified question :).

Comment: @pairwiseseq On a side note; `I think 2 [workers] from using command: ps aux | grep myApp | grep -v grep | wc -l`.  What you're seeing here is actually 1 master and 1 child process, which equates to 1 worker; see the [gunicorn design docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html) for a full explanation of this.

Comment: @v25 , it is working as intended only up to the `timeout` value I have set. In this case, I'd like the cache to expire/delete after 50 sec. I can try using `supervisor` to reload the app at a system level but was curious if I could do the "same" thing with cache timeout.